# Python Functions - Returning Values

Tags: python

Do call code paths in Python have to return a value?
**Like:**

```
def func(a):
    if a == 1:
        return a
    elif a == 2:
        dosomething()
    else:
        a += 2
```

Comment: why not try it and check yourself?

Answer (score 4):

No. If they don't, `None` is implicitly returned. But your calling function may get confused..

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is this 'good' practice to do this, or should everything return at least something for reference? I guess it does depend on what you're doing do that could be a very wide question.

Comment: No, just be careful to handle it properly outside. `return` is exactly the same as `return None`

Comment: The GoodPractice in this case is to explicitely return `None` (or whatever makes sense), as it will make the intent clear.